# .NET Counting vowels from a text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, text-files

As a newbie to .NET I decided to set myself the little challenge of writing a program to count the number of vowels from an input string. The program below works fine, but then, to develop this further I thought, instead of entering the string via console.readline, would it be possible to extract the text from a text file? I tried using the FileOpen/FileClose and StreamReader approach to resolve this issue with the mind set that the text file should be converted to a CharArray. Am I looking at this problem from completely the wrong angle? Can I customise my existing code and adapt it for text files, or do I need to adopt a completely new approach?

Any help most appreciated, Thanks

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim counter1 As Integer = 0
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a word")
    Dim myWord As String = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim charArray() As Char = myWord.ToCharArray()

    For Each letter In charArray
        Select Case letter
            Case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"
                counter1 = counter1 + 1
        End Select
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("The number of VOWELS in this word is " & counter1)

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in one line:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText("C:\input.txt"), "[aeiouAEIOU]").Count)
```

`File` is in the `System.IO` namespace, and `Regex` is in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace.

Just a note about this: while it's pretty rad that you can do this in one line, it's not always best to do things like this.  I like to keep method calls out in their own statements because it makes it easier to debug when you can see the value returned by each one.

Comment: Thanks for your time Rory. This looks a bit complicated for a newbie like me, but I'll look into it. Just wondering...would this work for other file types other than .txt?

Comment: A file extension is just a file extension....it doesn't mean anything except it helps the operating system figure out what default program is used to open it, and it helps you, the user, filter and sort your files.  You could change input.txt to input.pdf and your program would still read the text from it just fine --- the data hasn't changed.  If you double-clicked it, it would try to open in Adobe Acrobat or whatever your PDF application is, but it would fail because the data in the file is not binary/PDF...it's text.

Comment: So yes, it works with file types other than txt as long as the data is text encoded data -- ASCII, Unicode, etc.  YOu can even read "text" from a binary file (e.g. a *real* PDF) but it would just be a bunch of gibberish unicode characters because it's not intended to be text, the bits and bytes in the file are meant to be binary data interpret-able by whatever applications can open them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Select Case` check is probably pretty efficient, and can be adapted to count the vowels in a file easily.  You can use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) to iterate through the lines in a file, and use the `Select Case` check on each line.  This should work even on huge files, since it's not reading the whole file into memory.

```
Dim count = 0
For Each line In File.ReadLines("C:\BigTextFile.txt")
    For Each c In line
        Select Case c
            Case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"
                count += 1
        End Select
    Next
Next
Console.WriteLine(count)
```

Depending on your text file, you may need to [specify the encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383357(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks Mark for your time, most appreciated. I'm learning something new every day.